# Index of a curve is independent of the curve c?

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory

Index of a curve C:

$I_{C}$ is defined as the net number of counterclock wise revolutions made by the vector field as the vector field x moves once counterclockwise around the curve C.

If C is a simple closed curve enclosing an isolated fixed point $x^{\ast}$ the index is independent of the curve C as mentioned by Strogaz. I fail to see this. Can someone give me some insights?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The index is an integer, and so small changes (such as those done by a homotopy when the parameter changes slightly) can't change it (essentially because the index changes continuously, but it is also an integer, so...). Now you need to use compactness plus uniform continuity in the compact interval where the parameter of the homotopy runs.

Comment: A lot of the words used are strange to me. I'm actually going beyond, for most part, what my notes offers via Strogaz...Do you think you could water down the explanation-assuming you could.@Jonas

Comment: It is just a matter of proving, not of words. But Strogatz is a **very** bad book. Since you often don't give proper credit to answers, this is the best I can do.